# NullPointerException: add a check when taking a photo?

Tags: codenameone

Running the example https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/7fc101523955e8179fadd2c713a09e05 I received two times an odd crash report, regarding a NullPointerException. However the crash report is not very clear:

```
[EDT] 0:1:23,121 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.codename1.q.b.a.e()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.codename1.q.b.a.e()' on a null object reference
    at net.informaticalibera.test.capturephoto.b.b(MyApplication.java:99)
```

The line `MyApplication.java:99` is:
`galleryBtn.addActionListener(a -> CN.openGallery(l -> {`

I don't understand what can be null in that line.

For safety, I've just added `l != null` in the next line:
`if (l != null && l.getSource() != null) {`

but I'm not sure if this make sense... and, however, the crash report refers to the previous line.

What do you think about that crash report? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user cancels the operation then the event can be null which will result in an error here. This is purposely done to inform you that you should clean up UI that might be in place waiting for a selection.